# How can I trigger asp-validation behaviour manually in js?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I'm developing an ASP.Net core web application and I would like to implements client-side data validation. Is it possible to trigger the asp-validation-for tag helper behavior manually from javascript to show the validation error ?
In addition, when I'm returning a view with a Model with errors in ModelState, the span doesn't display error the same way as when the input for Something is empty ( normal  way and kendo display). How can I uniformized the display for validation ?

```
[Required]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

```
<span asp-validation-for="Something " class="text-danger"></span>
```

**Edit:**
I ommit to refer to  **jquery.validate.min.js** and **query.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**. Moreover, I had problems with validation from dynamic added elements to the DOMS via ajax request (as in [jquery-client-side-validation-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134949/jquery-client-side-validation-not-working-in-mvc3-partial-view/14135013#14135013)).

For the second part, I have two different types of validation display (one for ([Required attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd8GA.png)) and another one for ([Remote attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFuUd.png)). How can I always display the required validation display ?

Here is some code from my ViewModel:

```
 [Required] 
 [Remote(action: "CheckSomething", controller: "ControllerName")]
 public string Something { get; set; }
```

Here is some code from my View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.Something ).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" }))
<span asp-validation-for="Something " class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by `manual validate`, is it verified on the client through the submit button? You can achieve the client validation by referring to `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` , you can refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUX3PzyBofg . As for the second question, we need you to provide more detailed code to know the specific reason.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It helps me to find why my validation didn't work properly in the client side. I ommit to refer to jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js. Moreover, I had problems with validation from dynamic added elements to the DOMS via ajax request (as in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134949/jquery-client-side-validation-not-working-in-mvc3-partial-view/14135013#14135013)). For the second part of the question, I will edit my code my question to add infos about it