# How to prevent validation from non-selected rows in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have a requirement in MVC3. I have a simple form with a gridview with edit, update and delete button. 
When I update any record, validation should be fire for only that single row, not for other rows.

Comment: The more information you provide in your question (code, examples, errors), the better the answer will be. Right now we don't have much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking edit load a partial view into an Ajax dialog. Validation won't work on that loaded partial view, you'll have to tell jquery validate to parse that new content to validate it ala [MVC 3 Razor. Partial View validation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490322/mvc-3-razor-partial-view-validation-is-not-working)